# How do I insert a 2D array into another 2D array? (Ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm attempting to put an array of integers (eventually to be converted into their ASCII characters) into an array, framed by stars but it just isn't working and I don't know why.

My code is below and data is an array containing 40 columns and 22 rows.

```
image = Array.new(24) { Array.new(42, ' ')}
(0..23).each do |r|
  if r == 0 || r == 23 then
    (0..41).each do |c|
      image[r][c] = '*'
     end
  else
    (0..41).each do |c|
       if c == 0 || c == 41 then
         image[r][c] = '*' 
       else
         image[r][c] = data[r][c]
       end
    end
  end    
end


print image
```

Comment: I get ``undefined local variable or method `data'`` when trying to run your code. Please fix it and also include the current (wrong) output and the expected (correct) result.

Comment: If I add `data = Array.new(24) { Array.new(42, '-')}` then it works, though the output is really raw.

Answer (score 0):

You're making this way too complicated. Break it up into steps. Remove the nested loops and conditionals.

1) Grab rows 0 and 23 out of image and set everything to "*".

2) Iterate through each row (ie `image.each do |row| ...`) and set columns 0 and 41 to "*".

3) Iterate again through each row and set the other columns to match what's in data (a nested loop is probably necessary here, no conditional though).

Edit: full code could look something like this:

```
#step0 -- create nested array with first and last rows missing. Doesn't need useless spaces. Nil instead.
image = Array.new(22) { Array.new(42) }

#step1 --- iterate through the rows and set first and last columns to "*"
image.each do |row|
  row[0] = "*"
  row[41] = "*"
end

#step2 -- add first and last rows, which are all "*"
image.shift(Array.new(42, "*"))
image.push(Array.new(42, "*"))

#step3 -- nested loop that matches image to data only if not already set.
image.each_with_index do |row, ridx|
  row.each_with_index do |col, cidx|
    image[row][col] = data[row][col] unless image[row][col]
  end
end
```

It might actually just be easier to clone the data and then add that border to it. That is, after all, all you're doing here, and might be the source of the problem you're having.

Comment: I don't really understand steps 2 and 3? please could you explain further?

Comment: this is what i am doing for step 2:                                                        `image.each do |row|
  image[row][0] = "*"
  image[row][23] = "*"
end`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your case right and you have next values:

```
image = Array.new(5) { Array.new(10, ' ')}
data = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]]
```

Then minimum edits of your code should looks like:

```
(0..4).each do |r|
  (0..9).each do |c|
    if r == 0 || r == 4 || c == 0 || c == 9
      image[r][c] = '*'
    else
      image[r][c] = data[r.pred][c.pred]
    end
  end
end
```

Then result will looks like:

```
> image
#=> [["*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*"], ["*", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, "*"], ["*", 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, "*"], ["*", 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, "*"], ["*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*"]]
```

Comment: no that is not my data. How come my code does not work?

Comment: @twigface you don't add value of `data`

Answer (score 0):

Let's first construct `data`. For simplicity I assume `data` has `6` elements ("rows") and each element is an array of `4` elements (forming "columns", though Ruby actually has no concept of arrays having rows and columns).

```
ROWS = 6
COLS = 4

data = (ROWS*COLS).times.to_a.each_slice(4).to_a
  #=> [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15],
  #    [16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23]]
```

Now we need only modify your code slightly to produce the desired result.

```
rows = data.size+2
  #=> 8
cols = data.first+2    
  #=> 6
image = Array.new(rows) { Array.new(cols, ' ')}
(0...rows).each do |r| # note 3 dots here and below 
  if r == 0 || r == rows-1
    (0...cols).each do |c|
      image[r][c] = '*'
     end
  else
    (0...cols).each do |c|
       if c == 0 || c == cols-1
         image[r][c] = '*' 
       else
         image[r][c] = data[r-1][c-1]
       end
    end
  end    
end

image.each { |row| p row }
```

prints

```
["*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*"]
["*", 0, 1, 2, 3, "*"]
["*", 4, 5, 6, 7, "*"]
["*", 8, 9, 10, 11, "*"]
["*", 12, 13, 14, 15, "*"]
["*", 16, 17, 18, 19, "*"]
["*", 20, 21, 22, 23, "*"]
["*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*"]
```

A more Ruby-like way of doing this is as follows.

```
image = [['*']*(data.first.size+1)]
ROWS.times { |i| image << ['*', *data[i], '*'] }
image << image.first

image.each { |row| p row }
```

If you instead wanted to produce a nicely-formatted table, you could do the following.

```
def fmt(data, col_space, boundary_char='*')
  col_width = data.flatten.map { |n| n.to_s.size }.max + col_space
  nrows, ncols = data.size, data.first.size
  header = boundary_char * (col_width * ncols + 2 + col_space)
  right_border = " "*col_space << boundary_char
  image = [header]
  data.each { |row|
    image << "%s%s%s" %
      [boundary_char, row.map { |n| n.to_s.rjust(col_width) }.join, right_border] }
  image << header
  image   
end

puts fmt(data, 2)
```

prints

```
********************
*   0   1   2   3  *
*   4   5   6   7  *
*   8   9  10  11  *
*  12  13  14  15  *
*  16  17  18  19  *
*  20  21  22  23  *
********************
```

The steps are as follows (`data` as defined above).

```
col_space = 2
boundary_char='*'

a = data.flatten
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
  #    15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23] 
b = a.map { |n| n.to_s.size }
  #=> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] 
col_width = b.max + col_space
  #=> 2 + 2 => 4 

nrows, ncols = data.size, data.first.size
  #=> [6, 4] 
header = boundary_char * (col_width * ncols + 2 + col_space)
  #=> * * (4*4 + 2 + 2)
  #=> "********************" 
right_border = " "*col_space << boundary_char
  #=> " "*2 << "*" =< " " << "*" => "  *" 
image = [header]
  #=> ["********************"] 

data.each { |row|
  puts "row=#{row}"
  puts "  image row=#{"%s%s%s" % [boundary_char,
    row.map { |n| n.to_s.rjust(col_width) }.join, right_border]}"
  image << "%s%s%s" % [boundary_char,
    row.map { |n| n.to_s.rjust(col_width) }.join, right_border] }

row=[0, 1, 2, 3]
  image row=*   0   1   2   3  *
row=[4, 5, 6, 7]
  image row=*   4   5   6   7  *
row=[8, 9, 10, 11]
  image row=*   8   9  10  11  *
row=[12, 13, 14, 15]
  image row=*  12  13  14  15  *
row=[16, 17, 18, 19]
  image row=*  16  17  18  19  *
row=[20, 21, 22, 23]
  image row=*  20  21  22  23  *
```

Then

```
image << header
image
```

returns the result above.